# How to provide image source to <img> from XML?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, sql

I am loading a repeater on scroll down. I am trying to display name of message sender, message and image thumbnail of the sender. Everything is working fine except the image. I am seeing name/path of the image as text instead of image itself.

```
[WebMethod]
    public static string GetCustomers(int pageIndex, int qstr)
    {
        return GetCustomersData(pageIndex,qstr).GetXml();
    }
```

**XML**

```
<Customers>
        <RowNumber>11</RowNumber>
        <MsgId>12</MsgId>
        <sentby>Matt</sentby>
        <sentTo>John</sentTo>
        <Msg>ok?</Msg>
        <ImageName>935604602.jpg</ImageName>
      </Customers>
```

Now i have this code on **aspx**..

```
function OnSuccess(response) {
        var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(response.d);
        var xml = $(xmlDoc);
        pageCount = parseInt(xml.find("PageCount").eq(0).find("PageCount").text());
        var customers = xml.find("Customers");
        customers.each(function () {
            var customer = $(this);
            var table = $("#dvCustomers table").eq(0).clone(true);
            $(".MsgId", table).html(customer.find("MsgId").text());
            $(".sentby", table).html(customer.find("sentby").text());
            $(".sentTo", table).html(customer.find("sentTo").text());
            $(".Msg", table).html(customer.find("Msg").text());
            $(".ImageThumb", table).html(customer.find("ImageUrl").text());
 $("#dvCustomers").append(table).append("");
        });
        $("#loader").hide();
    }
```

**Repeater Code**

```
   <asp:Repeater ID="rptCustomers" runat="server" >
        <ItemTemplate>
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="width: 400px; height: 50px;
            border: dashed 0px #04AFEF; background-color:#F1EEE5">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <b><u><span class="sentby" style="color:#A52A2A;"><%# Eval("sentby") %></span></u></b>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>                       
                    <b> <span class="ImageThumb"><img src= "<%# Eval("ImageUrl") %>" alt="Title #0" width="70" height="70" /></a></b></span> 
                                        <span class="Msg"><%# Eval("Msg")%></span>                                          
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
  </div>
```

Everything is working fine except the image. I am seeing name/path of the image in text instead of image itself.

Comment: Change your jquery selector.

Comment: can you post the rendered html code?

Comment: @SandorA catch me. Was more quick than me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

`$(".ImageThumb > img", table).attr('src', customer.find("ImageUrl").text());`

There may also be a mismatch between your XML `<ImageName>` and your jQuery `find("ImageUrl")`

Comment: it is not working, should i change this also.. `<b> <span class="ImageThumb"><img src= "<%# Eval("ImageName") %>" alt="Title #0" width="70" height="70" /></a></b></span>       `

Comment: Yes, you should use the same name from your XML.

Comment: I already did that is there anything apart from that?  Because its not working.

Comment: Not really, that should work. Are you still seeing the name/path of the image in text?

Comment: No i am not seeing it in text anymore. i used firebug and i found `<b>
<span class="ImageThumb">
<img width="70" height="70" src="911353134.jpg">
</span>
</b>` to be faded

Comment: the path was wrong , i changed it to  UserImage/911353134.jpg and its working :) Thanks!